# CSS: how can I hide a div when its text doesn't fit?

Tags: html, css

When my website is displayed on screens with a smaller width like phones, one div floats below the navigation bar so I want to hide it. How can I do that using pure CSS?

[image: Screenshot]

I already tried some things like using "text-overflow: hidden;" and "overflow: hidden;" but those don't seem to work, or I'm using them in a wrong way.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="credits">
  <span class="nav">
    <a class="credits" href="http://github.com/jvnknvlgl/website">Made by jvnknvlgl</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
div.credits {
  float: right;
}

span.nav {
  line-height: 56px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a.credits {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I guess you need javascript or jquery to check whether it exceeds width. Do you want to achieve this only with html and css

Comment: you can use media query for it from css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick media query should be enough. Add this after your CSS :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) { // adjust the width for your needs
    div.credits {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to hide the excess.

Comment: That is not what I understand by "one div floats below the navigation bar so I want to hide it".

Comment: Oh nvm, that's what I thought since he tried to use overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use media tag for responsive design like:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 420px) { // your screen widths
  div.credits {
     overflow: hidden;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to hide all items that don't fit, just set a static height to your navigation (container) and set `overflow:hidden;`

Alternatively, you could use ellipsis overflow:

```
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: some width;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your div's size is not declared, then it will just expand, making overflow: hidden; useless.

Add a height and width% on your div if you can.